# What's the right terminology for "white" and "black" people? / Richtiger Begriff für Schwarz und Weiß

Tags: single-word-request, political-correctness

(for English, scroll down)

Ich habe in [*Der Spiegel, Kultur*](http://www.spiegel.de/spiegel/kulturspiegel/d-126223297.html) folgendes Interview mit dem aus Kamerun stammenden Kurator Simon Njami gesehen:

> »Ich finde auch die englische Übersetzung des Stücktitels falsch. Es heißt im Original "Les Nègres", also sollte es "The Niggers" heißen, nicht "The Blacks" [...] Und schwarze Menschen, das ist offensichtlich, sind ohnehin nicht wirklich schwarz.«  Aus „Es geht um Freiheit“ zugleich aus [Schwarz auf Weiß](http://www.spiegel.de/spiegel/kulturspiegel/d-126223297.html).

Es lässt sich daher vermuten, dass der quasi richtige Begriff für sehr dunkelhäutige Menschen *Schwarz* sein könnte, aber auch dass einige Menschen die Verwendung dieses Wortes nicht ganz akzeptieren würden.

Was ist der richtige Begriff für sehr hell- und sehr dunkelhäutige Menschen? Ich hätte gerne zwei Bezeichnungen: eine, die man in etwa einem Vortrag erwähnen könnte, und eine zweite, die eher nicht nach Überkorrektheit klingt, aber gleichzeitig politisch korrekt ist, also niemanden beleidigen würde.

---

What are the correct German terms to refer to skin colour? Does one say *weiß* and *schwarz*? I've found this discussion in [*Der Spiegel, Kultur*](http://www.spiegel.de/spiegel/kulturspiegel/d-126223297.html), and there says Simon Njami

> 'Ich finde auch die englische Übersetzung des Stücktitels falsch. Es heißt im Original "Les Nègres", also sollte es "The Niggers" heißen, nicht "The Blacks". [...] Und schwarze Menschen, das ist offensichtlich, sind ohnehin nicht wirklich schwarz.'

I ask here for both, a completely right term for *Weiß* and *Schwarz*, the one one would say by giving a talk, and a usual one, but still politically correct.

Comment: Ich musste sofort an [das hier](http://www.csectioncomics.com/2014/01/politically-correctness-101.html) denken

Comment: Wieso möchtest Du in einem Vortrag eine Bezeichnung nutzen, die »nach Überkorrektheit klingt«? Mal abgesehen davon, dass ich es fragwürdig finde, so etwas zu unterstützen, kann sich gerade dadurch jemand beleidigt fühlen. »eine [], die eher nicht nach Überkorrektheit klingt, aber gleichzeitig politisch korrekt ist« ist meistens ein Widerspruch in sich. »niemanden zu beleidigen« ist unmöglich, da es Leute gibt, die sich allein durch die Tatsache beleidigt fühlen, dass Du überhaupt ein Wort dafür nutzt – selbst zur Beschreibung historischer Begebenheiten oder auf einer Vermisstenanzeige.

Comment: @c.p.: Du hast mich falsch verstanden. Ich kritisiere nicht die Nutzung von Begriffen für diesen Unterschied; ich bezweifle nur, dass es Begriffe gibt, die das leisten, was Du wünscht. Es ist auf diesem Gebiet unmöglich, es allen recht zu machen, und man sollte es meines Erachtens auch nicht damit übertreiben, es zu versuchen.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Alles klar. Ich verstehe.

Comment: Die Kritik an der Unterscheidung zw. Schwarz und Weiß ist nicht, bzw. vorwiegend nicht eine Kritik am benutzten Begriff, sondern an der Unterscheidung selbst. In den wenigen Kontexten, in denen eine solche Unterscheidung nötig ist, hängt es aber vom Kontext ab, was Du ausdrücken willst. Sehr dunkelhäutige Menschen gibt es auch in Indien oder nach Besuch der Sonnenbank. Die meisten Menschen bezeichnen auch Obama als Schwarz, obwohl er eine weiße Mutter hat, und daher mit gleichem Recht als Weiss bezeichnet werden könnte.

Comment: Interessant, dass im Kontext mit »Schwarzen« auch »Personen, aus der Gothic-, Metal-, Cyberszene und vergleichbaren Szenen« gemeint werden kann … Ich nutze »Schwarze« ausschließlich in dem Kontext (und zähle mich dann zu den Schwarzen).

Comment: @Jan Je nach Kontext kann damit auch ein Mitglied der C-Parteien gemeint sein, in früheren Zeiten ein Schiedsrichter, jmd. mit Nachnamen  Schwarzer usw.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Die [Bundeszentrale für politische Bildung](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundeszentrale_f%C3%BCr_politische_Bildung) hat einen [Formulierungs-Ratgeber für Journalisten](http://www.bpb.de/politik/extremismus/rechtsextremismus/41722/kleiner-formulierungs-ratgeber-fuer-journalisten) veröffentlicht (ausführlichere Fassung als [PDF](http://www.derbraunemob.de/shared/download/info_journal_rstraf.pdf)). Mitgewirkt haben unter anderem

- [Der Braune Mob e. V.](http://derbraunemob.de/),
- [Initiative Schwarze Menschen in Deutschland Bund e. V.](http://isdonline.de/)
- [ADEFRA e. V. – Schwarze Frauen in Deutschland](http://www.adefra.com/) und
- [Amadeu Antonio Stiftung](http://www.amadeu-antonio-stiftung.de/).

Wie bereits die Namen zweier Vereine erahnen lassen:

> Die politisch korrekte Ausdrucksweise für schwarze Menschen wäre: **Schwarze Menschen**.

Diese Bezeichnung solle auch verwendet werden, wenn die Hautfarbe nicht tatsächlich der Farbe Schwarz entspricht, denn ein „Abstufungs-Drang“ bestehe auch bei anderen „Gruppen“ (wohl: Hautfarben) nicht:

> […] wenn Portugiesen, Norweger und Stéphanie von Monaco angeblich gleichermassen "weiß" sind (zu wieviel Prozent dies in Wirklichkeit der Fall ist, wird ja auch nicht als relevant betrachtet), weil dies die Bezeichnung für ihre soziokulturelle Grupe [sic] ist, so trifft dies im selben Maße auch für die Gruppe Schwarzer Menschen zu.

#### Nicht »Farbig«

> Laut der "Initiative Schwarze Menschen in Deutschland", ADEFRA (Schwarze Frauen in Deutschland) und weiteren Experten gibt es keine **Farbigen**.

Genannte Argumente:

- Begriff stammt aus Kolonialzeit (stark koloniale Konnotation); hat in den 50ern das als rassistisch erkannte Wort »Neger« ersetzt
- unnötiger und exotisierender Euphemismus
- impliziert, dass weiß die Norm sei
- »farbig« besänftigt die Tatsache, dass sie schwarz sind; als sei es nicht in Ordnung, schwarz zu sein
- farbig sagt nichts weiter aus, als dass die Person nicht weiß ist

Comment: Die meisten als schwarz bezeichneten Menschen sind aber dunkelbraun bis hellbraun.

Comment: Wie das obige Zitat zeigt sind auch nicht alle Weißen gleichermaßen weiß. Ich beanspruche für mich in Zukunft toastbrot-milchig als politisch korrekte Auszeichnung meiner Hautfarbe. ;-)

Comment: Gute Antwort! Da sieht man mal wieder, wie die Sittenwächter hin und her schwanken. Ich habe die Zeit erlebt, wo „schwarz“ zu Gunsten von „farbig“ verteufelt wurde.

Answer (score 12):

Die meisten „schwarzen“ Menschen in meinem Bekanntenkreis ziehen es vor als „dunkelhäutig“ bezeichnet zu werden. Allerdings ist es ihnen am liebsten, wenn man sie gar nicht von den anderen Menschen unterscheidet.

Most of the “black” people I know prefer to be called “dark skinned”. Even better than that, though, would be not to single them out at all.

Answer (score 8):

Slippery slope :)

> I ask here for both a completely right term for Weiß and Schwarz, the one one would say by giving a talk, and a usual one, but still politically correct.

White is simple, it’s weiß. *Weiße* to denote people of Caucasian descent is not offensive to anyone (that I know of), and widely used. The same is actually true for people of color, who we refer to as *Schwarze* (black) or *Farbige* (people of color), without too many problems. I suppose you could call them *Afrikaner* (Africans) as well. Today all these terms are not considered racist by the majority of German speakers and to the best of my knowledge used by the affected as well.

This is no longer true for *Neger*, which used to be a neutral term (derived from *niger*, the Latin word for *black*) but is no longer considered acceptable, and obviously it never was for some other explicit racial slurs I won’t go into.

> Es lässt sich denn vermuten, dass der quasi richtige Begriff für sehr dunkelhäutigen Menschen Schwarz sein könnte, aber auch dass einige Menschen die Verwendung dieses Wortes nicht ganz akzeptieren würden.

We are talking about “Die Neger” here (i.e., “the Negroes”), *nicht* “die Schwarzen”. It’s meant to be provocative, of course.

There is one important tidbit to add: Quite a number of people consider the whole concept of “race” offensive. You do not talk about “Rasse” in polite (German) society.

Comment: Actually **Afrikaner** is not used if you're not sure the person is actually from Africa. You can't call a black person from France **Afrikaner**.

Comment: I suppose it's like calling somebody from the Caribbean an "African American". Not correct, obviously, but not the end of the world. It's probably best to ask the people concerned how they want to be addresses.

Comment: Außerdem gibt es etliche Afrikaner, deren Hautfarbe eher weiß als schwarz ist, insbesondere nördlich der Sahara.

Comment: At the moment there is no "political correct" way to express it. "Neger" was in the 1950s absolutely correct, I own an encyclopedia that uses this expression. But now it is banned from the vocabulary (to be provocative its use would be correct).

Comment: @RRZEurope: Als ob eine Enzyklopädie nicht auch rassistisch sein könnte. In den 50ern gab es in den USA noch Rassentrennung im Bus und m.W. in der Universität.

Comment: Kaukasier ist eine rassistische Phantasiebildung die über 100 Jahre alt, und längst widerlegt ist. Die Bezeichnung als Weißer wäre sehr wohl in den meisten Fällen eine Geschmacklosigkeit und wird vermieden. Als Personenbeschreibung ist die Differenzierung zw. zwei Hautfarben auch ziemlich dürftig.

Comment: It's not really my fault that the term (i.e., Caucasian) is widely used in English, and has a certain fixed meaning there, is it? To call somebody "white" is certainly not considered "tasteless" by most people, but obviously there are exceptions, yourself included. Duly noted.

Comment: @Ingmar: Ist die Tatsache, dass es nicht Deine Schuld ist, ein Beleg dafür, dass die Terminologie nicht rassistisch ist? Dass Weiße und Kaukasier als Betroffene die Begriffe nicht als rassistisch betrachten könnte damit zu tun haben, dass sie nie oder fast nie mit diesen bezeichnet werden.

Comment: Das mag für Mitteleuropa vielleicht zutreffen, mit Sicherheit aber nicht zB für die USA. Und kein Weißer (sorry) dort stößt sich an den Begriffen. Aber Du kannst das natürlich gerne anders sehen.

Comment: "Weiße to denote people of Caucasian descent is not offensive to anyone (that I know of)"

I'm sure you would be pleased to make my acquaintance, then. I find the term and the concept behind it unutterably racist and offensive. It is an antiquated colonial idea that Americans used to rebuild their civil society after their Civil War, and does not belong in Europe.

Answer (score 2):

Politisch korrekt ist, die Hautfarbe (oder Haarfarbe, Augenfarbe, Behinderung, Kleidung, Bildung, Nationalität, Religion, Alter, Sexualität, …) nur dann zu erwähnen, wenn sie für den **Kontext wirklich relevant** ist. (Ausgerechnet beim Geschlecht gibt es lustigerweise auch gegenteilige Ansichten.) Als Substantiv oder als Gruppenbezeichnung sind solche Charakteristika immer grenzwertig, weil sie Konnotationen wecken, die vor allem in einem Sachtext meistens unnötig sind. Für die Bild ist es bspw. natürlich immer relevant, welche Hautfarbe, Religion und Nationalität ein möglicher Straftäter hat, weil ihre Texte stets einer Agenda folgen, während sich echte Zeitungen um Neutralität bemühen (aber regelmäßig dabei versagen).

Es gibt anthropologische Skalen, um Haut- (z.B. [Fitzpatrick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitzpatrick_scale)), Augen- (Martin–Schultze) und Haarfarbe (Fischer–Saller) einigermaßen neutral zu erfassen, die natürlich vor allem in der ersten Hälfte des letzten Jahrhundert auch regelmäßig missbraucht wurden, um Rassentheorien zu stützen. Wenn sie tatsächlich eine Variable in der vorgestellten Untersuchung bilden, kann man diese Einteilungen in einem wissenschaftlichen Vortrag verwenden: „Hauttyp fünf“ ist unbedenklich.

[image: Etwas zweifelhafte Karte zur globalen indigenen Hautfarbenverteilung aus Wikipedia, die sieben stat.]

In Bezeichnungen wie *Schwarze*, *Farbige*, *Weiße*, *Schlitzaugen*, *Blondinen* schwingen immer auch andere phänotypische Vorstellungen mit, die in der eigenen Perzeption und Konstruktion von Wirklichkeit mit der jeweiligen Farbe oder anderen Eigenschaft korrelieren. Dass jemand bspw. bei *Neger* an krause Haare, breite Nasen, wulstige Lippen oder große Penisse denkt, ist allein noch kein so großes Problem, aber daneben werden zwangsläufig auch soziale Merkmale assoziiert, die gerade bei diesem Begriff stark in Richtung ‚triebgesteuerter, minderbemittelter Untermensch‘ gehen oder v.a. in historischem Sprachgebrauch auch einfach ‚Sklave‘ meinen. Für *Nigger* gilt das im Prinzip noch extremer, aber das Wort war und ist im Deutschen ohnehin [unüblich](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Neger%2CNegroide%2BNegroider%2CNegro%2BNegros%2CNigger%2CSchwarze%2BSchwarzer%2CFarbige%2BFarbiger%2CMohr%2BMohren%2CAfrikaner%2BSchwarzafrikaner%2CAfroamerikaner%2CDunkelh%C3%A4utige%2BDunkelh%C3%A4utiger%2Cpeople+of+color%2BPeople+of+Color&year_start=1750&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3).

Leider tendieren nahe Begriffe wie hier *Schwarze* und *Farbige* leicht dazu, als Synonyme gebraucht und verstanden zu werden, weswegen sie trotz ihrer scheinbar einfachen, transparenten Bedeutung eben häufig auch die problematischen Konnotationen transportieren.
Es ist, was manchen nicht einleuchten will, für erfolgreiche Kommunikation weniger wichtig, was man selbst beim Sprechen oder Schreiben meint, sondern das, was die anderen beim Lesen oder Hören verstehen. Wie sehr man das berücksichtigen kann und will, bleibt jedem selbst überlassen. 
In dem erwähnten Theatertitel „Les Nègres“ könnte – ich kenne den Inhalt nicht – bspw. gerade die abwertende Bedeutungsebene gezielt gewählt und treffend sein, es ist ja kein Sachtext.

Deswegen gibt es auf die Frage keine Antwort in der gewünschten Form eines bestimmten Wortes, sondern nur als Handlungsanweisung: Wenn man einen plausiblen Grund hat, ein bestimmtes (körperliches) Merkmal einer Person zu erwähnen oder sogar daraus eine Gruppe zu konstituieren, dann kann und sollte man das **Merkmal beim Namen nennen**, aber es vermeiden, die Individuen oder Gruppen darauf zu reduzieren.

Answer (score 0):

In English they are talking about Caucasians for white people. Schwarzer, Weißer: these are quite broad terms.

How about Nigerian - German?
European - African?
Asian - Southamerican?

Generally you can call all non-whites **farbig**. But according to Wikipedia this is also a term that is already seen as problematic.

> If you want to highlight the dark **skin colour** just call them **dunkelhäutige Menschen.**

If you want to highlight their **origin**, call them Africans, Asians, Europeans, Americans, Canadians.

> The opposite of **dunkelhäutige Menschen** is **hellhäutige Menschen.**

Referring to "them" as Menschen is the key here. We are all Menschen, all that differs are the properties of our bodies. So you can modify this to any other property like red-haired, skinny, fat, dumb, intelligent, nice, cool, T-Rex. You get the drift.

Comment: Der Terminus des Kaukasiers ist wissenschaftlich nicht haltbar. Dass man dies als Rasse in offiziellen Formularen wie einem Visum einträgt macht die Sache nicht besser - es gibt keine kaukasische Rasse. Die Hautfarbe als kaukasisch zu bezeichnen ist auch Humbug.

Comment: Nigerianer ist auch keine Hautfarbe, auch Amerikaner, Canadier nicht.

Comment: Ich habe nie im Leben in Deutschland den Begriff "Kaukasier" gehört. Nicht einmal. Und in Großbritannien hört man "Caucasian" nur in amerikanischen Fernsehprogrammen, > 90% aller "Caucasians" sind entweder Mörder oder Opfer :-)

Comment: "Farbig" ist für die meisten nicht-weißen Menschen falsch, und für die anderen heute beleidigend.